# Android BroadcastReceiver set up an alarm

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I need access of android getSystemService to set up an alarm inside an Notification's code.

Am I able to pass the getSystemService to the broadcast receiver?
If not how can I set up an alarm inside an broadcast receiver's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use context from `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` 
to get system service  `context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)`